# Wheat crackers that are ha'adama

Tags: blessing, food

[Paskesz](http://paskesz.com/) (a brand that makes lots of kosher Jewish food in the USA), makes wheat crackers. The crackers are 99% wheat (per the ingredients label). While most wheat crackers require the blessing of mezonot, these are specifically labelled as needing the bracha of ha'adama. What is Paskesz doing (or as I suspect is the case, not doing) to these crackers such that they're ha'adama?
[image: Paskesz wheat crackers] [image: Label showing bracha]

Comment: the ingredients indicate no water. If one were to take a wheat stalk and chomp on it, what would the bracha be?

Comment: @rosends Ha’adamah

Comment: @JoelK then based on the ingredients, isn't that the right bracha for these cracker?

Comment: @rosends It’s not clear to me how these crackers are manufactured, but yes, it could very well be

Comment: Water is very often not listed in the ingredients for baked goods, since it provides no nutrients (calories, vitamins, minerals, etc.) and is not an allergen. So lack of water in the ingredients listing does not mean much. As the answer shows, this is indeed a non-water process, but you can't tell from the ingredients. Matzah will list "wheat flour and water only" but that is for Halachic emphasis, not for the usual "ingredient" reasons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refer to this communication between Dayan Westheim zt"l and Rabbi Yehoshua Kaganoff [here](https://guardyoureyes.com/GYEFiles/PDFs/Addiction%20in%20Halocho.pdf) on p.64. The full letter is very enlightening and sheds light on their production/manufacture and the resulting halachic breakdown:

It is worth noting that the argument for them being ha'adamah is as follows:

> Regarding the proper Brocho on the Paskesz product of Wheat Squares: Thank you for describing to me their production processing, i.e., **complete whole wheat kernels including their bran are placed between two metal plates approximately 3/4 inch distant from each other and then they are heated until they pop. Simultaneous to their popping they become fused together to form the "pattycake"-like format** as it appears when it is marketed.
>
> I had posited that this would be equivalent to a cooking process "bishul" of whole wheat kernels until they completely disintegrated and adhered to each other of which the [MB 208:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.208.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (end) states that the Brocho is Borei Minei Mezonos. You countered that all of this discussion in the Shulchon Aruch and Acharonim revolved about only a liquid based processing but **a dry process such as the puffing/popping of the grains as described above would not engender any discussion or dispute and would unanimously be Borei Pri Ho'Adomo**.